# How to set status bar color if using sliver app bar

Tags: flutter, flutter-theme

As I am having sliver app bar in my screen, I am not using AppBar() widget. So by default the status bar color is white.

Is there a way to change the color of status bar from sliver.

[image]

Below code works for Android as expected, but not for iOS.

```
SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(SystemUiOverlayStyle(
    statusBarColor: kPrimaryColor,
  ));
```

If using app bar to change the color, then sliver breaks
[image]

Comment: Have yo tried AnnotatedRegion?

Comment: Yes @MohanSaiManthri, just tried but it didn't worked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add `color` what you need and set `pinned` to false

```
SliverAppBar(
      backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
      expandedHeight: 160.0,
      pinned: false,
      stretch: false,
)
```

Comment: I have tried this, but it doesn't work

Comment: i tried in my project, this should work, show code how you tried please

Comment: Hi @novol, here is the source code of a sample app.
https://github.com/jitangupta/flutter-architecture

Comment: you use `SafeArea`, maybe this is a problem, try remove or add `top: false`

Comment: it worked, thank you so much. it was a big help.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
Scaffold(
    body: SafeArea(
      top: false,
      bottom: false,
      child: Container(), // Replace this container with your UI widget
    ),
)
```

Comment: This breaks scrolling behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

Add systemOverlayStyle to sliver app bar

`SliverAppBar( systemOverlayStyle:const SystemUiOverlayStyle( statusBarColor: Colors.transparent, ), ),`

Comment: This did the trick for me